# Why does .deployed() in truffle with testrpc return first address?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I created a simple contract and deployed in with testrpc using truffle migrate. In the contract I have a variable

`creator = msg.sender;`

When calling the contract, it shows that the contract is always called on the first address from the 10 addresses in testrpc.

This is how i call the contract in the truffle console:

`var instanceTest
 MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) { instanceTest = instance; })
 instanceTest.creator.call()`

This returns the first address from the list of addresses in the chain. Why is it the first and how do I call the contract on another address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle uses the first the default address so `msg.sender` would be `accounts[0]`

To change it use this:

```
var creatorAddress = accounts[0];
var firstOwnerAddress = accounts[1];
var secondOwnerAddress = accounts[2];
var externalAddress = accounts[3];
```

So know you have these address that you can use in your code:

To call a function from these addresses just use this:

```
 var instanceTest
 MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) { instanceTest = instance; })
 instanceTest.creator.call({from: firstOwnerAddress})
```

Notice I used from within the curly braces in the call parameter.